expo-configure-project.sh: Operation not permitted from Xcode after trying to 'Archive' app
My app is built using React native and Expo (in bare workflow)
Everything where running fine on  android and ios even using a build from Xcode. Then I tried to archive the app with "Any ios device" target (don't know if this is linked to the issue)
But I see the error:

.../expo-configure-project.sh: Operation not permitted

Seeing this issue : Expo/EAS Build "expo-configure-project.sh: No such file or directory" error
I've try checking expo-module-core and expo-modules-autolinking which were installed.
I've tried to update my expo modules:
npx expo install --fix

then update the ios project :
npx expo prebuild --platform ios
npx pod-install

and run the project again with 'clean' flag
npx expo start -c

After that, the app can be run again from command line (it was not running anymore with the same error)
But still from xcode, either I RUN or ARCHIVE,  I've got the error

Run custom Shell script '[expo] Configure project' (0.9s)
Showing All Messages bash: ./Pods/Target Support
Files/Pods-Appname/expo-configure-project.sh: Operation not permitted
Showing All Messages
Sandbox: bash(93359) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/username/Documents/Workspace/projectName/appName/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AppName/expo-configure-project.sh

I've check the script file exist and has permission set right:

-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myusername  staff    1710  4 jul 11:13 expo-configure-project.sh

More info from command line 'expo run:ios':

❌  error: Sandbox: bash(33597) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/guillaume/Documents/Workspace/Project/Appname/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Appname/expo-configure-project.sh (in target 'TargetName' from project 'ProjectName')

Thank you for any advice.
Versions info :
"react-native": "0.74.3"
"expo": "~51.0.17" 
"expo-modules-core": "^1.12.17" 
"expo-modules-autolinking": "~1.11.0"

Xcode v15.4

Anyone explain the downvote plz ?

After a few hours struggling with this, I've tried removing the problematic build phase (Expo configure project)  The error then occured on another file during another build phase, so I figured it was linked to a project misconfiguration.
Searching for a more specific response on the "Sandbox: deny file read data..."  error, I've found this topic:
Sandbox: bash(72986) deny(1) file-write-data /Users/XXX/ios/Pods/resources-to-copy-XXXShareExtension.txt
The answer is to disable the "User script sandboxing" in build settings.
So update your Xcode project build option 'ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING' to 'No' to remove the error.
